# Overriding UIImageView's image getter/setter methods

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, overriding

I'm subclassing a UIImageView, so that each time the image property is set an animation occurs.  The following was successful:

```
import UIKit

class AnimatedImageView: UIImageView {

var img: UIImage! {
    get {
        return self.image
    }
    set {
        self.image = newValue

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.4, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.2, initialSpringVelocity: 5.0, options: .CurveEaseIn, animations: {_ in

            self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.1, 1.1);

            }, completion: {_ in
                self.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        })
    }
}
```

This is no surprise. I subclassed UIImageView and added an entirely new variable called 'img', which in turn modifies UIImageView's 'image' property.

The issue is that the end-user could conceivably still alter AnimatedImageView's 'image' property.

```
import UIKit

class AnimatedImageView: UIImageView {

override var image: UIImage! {
 get {
     return self.image
 }
 set {
    self.image = newValue

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.4, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.2, initialSpringVelocity: 5.0, options: .CurveEaseIn, animations: {_ in

        self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.1, 1.1);

        }, completion: {_ in
            self.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    })
 }
}
```

Sure enough this causes a stackoverflow because when I call `self.image = newValue` it repeatedly calls the setter method that I've overridden in my subclass.  So, what's the right way to override the getter/setter methods of the 'image' property on UIImageView

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just use `super.image` instead, that will prevent a loop.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using super.image would be to reference the image via the ivar _image.  This references it directly, without calling the getter, and avoids the loop.

```
import UIKit

class AnimatedImageView: UIImageView {

override var image: UIImage! {
 get {
     return _image
 }
 set {
    _image = newValue

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.4, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.2, initialSpringVelocity: 5.0, options: .CurveEaseIn, animations: {_ in

        self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.1, 1.1);

        }, completion: {_ in
            self.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    })
 }
```